# bss segment size with global arrays

Tags: gcc, memory, elf

I have a code with several uninitialized global variables, for the sake of simplicity, let's say 3:

```
int global_uninitialized_0;
int global_uninitialized_1;
int global_uninitialized_2;
```

When compiling this code, the size of bss is reported by size is 16.

If I added more global uninitialized variables, the bss grows as expected.
Yet, if I use an array of ints, it grows more than I would expect:

```
int global_uninitialized_0;
int global_uninitialized_1;
int global_uninitialized_2[4];
```

When compiling this code, the size of bss is reported by size is 48.
Notice, when using an array of 3 elements, the bss grows as expected as well.

Why this discrepancy? I'd say there is some sort of alignment, but I couldn't find anything related to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When compiling your test for `x86_64`, I observe the following layout:

```
 readelf -Ws t.o | grep ' global'
     2: 0000000000000000     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 global_uninitialized_0
     3: 0000000000000004     4 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 global_uninitialized_1
     4: 0000000000000010    16 OBJECT  GLOBAL DEFAULT    3 global_uninitialized_2
```

The size of `.bss` (32 bytes here) makes perfect sense when you consider that the `global_uninitialized_2` starts 16 bytes into the `.bss` section, so the question is: why did the compiler decide to leave an 8-byte hole between `global_uninitialized_1` and `global_uninitialized_2`?

I am guessing that GCC tries to align this array on 16-byte boundary for cache alignment purpose.

If you change the definition of `global_uninitialized_2` to only require 4-byte alignment:

```
__attribute__((aligned(4))) int global_uninitialized_2[4];
```

then you get a 24-byte `.bss` and the array is allocated immediately after the single `int`.